# Function return 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, function, undefined

I have a javascript function which always returns 'undefined'. Please help.

```
function GetUserInfo()
{
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var result;
    var query = new Parse.Query("UserInfo");
    query.equalTo("UserID", "1234");
    var run = query.find({
    success: function(results) {    
        result = results;
    },
    error: function(error) {
        result = error;
    }
  }); // find       
    return result;          
}

   var item = GetUserInfo();       // always return 'undefined'
```

Comment: Look very closely at your function `GetUserInfo` and see if you can find a place where it returns anything. (Hint: the return inside the callback is **not** a return from `GetUserInfo`.) The return value of a function is `undefined` if it has no explicit `return` statement.

Answer (score 1):

If a JavaScript function does not explicitly return a value, the value returned will always be `undefined`. In this case, you don't have a return statement for your `GetUserInfo()` function. There's a return statement in the `query.find` success callback, but that only returns within the scope of the callback, and does not return a value for the parent function.

If `query.find` is synchronous, you can assign the value of `results` to a variable created outside of your callback function. However, if `query.find` is asynchronous, you'll need to wait for the for the callback to run and return before your parent function can return a value.

Try stepping through your function, and logging the results of your query. That will give you a better idea of what's going on inside your function.

Comment: The cause of the problem is not that the callback may not return anything, it is that the `GetUserInfo` function is not returning anything.

Comment: That's precisely what I was saying. I'll update to clarify. :)

Comment: I am sure the results.length is equal to 1. The statement 'GetUserInfo = results;' would return the result, wouldn't it?

Comment: @ChuongLam Afraid not. 1) The name of a JavaScript function doesn't represent its `return` value. 2) The other Q&A linked above explains this far more thoroughly, but `results` really can't be `return`ed from `GetUserInfo()`. With `query.find()` being asynchronous (in its own time), `GetUserInfo()` will actually exit and assign `item` before the `results` have become available.

Comment: You are right. I just edited the code to make sure the query.find() completed and returned value. But it still not to work. Can you point out what is wrong?

Comment: @ChuongLam With asynchronous code, you'll want to become familiar with using callbacks (at least with current standards). Example: http://jsfiddle.net/a4fL6s6s/.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. Your code works wonderful.